# what does ensureIndex() commad do in java/scala mongo driver when its called multiple times

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, shell

I am new to indexing in mongodb i want to ask 
if i do this in mongo shell

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex({"Email":1})
```

It creates the index successfully but if again run this command mongo shell displays this message

```
{ "numIndexesBefore" : 2, "note" : "all indexes already exist", "ok" : 1 }
```

Which is the desired  case when i do the same in my scala/java code

```
class Test {

def myFunction= {

var index=collection.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("Email":1))
}

}
```

when i call this functions two times it does not throw any exception as the mongo shell does of `index already exist` so i want to know what does this command

```
collection.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("Email":1))
    }
```

do when we call it again like

```
object Demo extends App 
{
var t=Test()
t.myFunction
t.myFunction//what happends here ? what does this ensureIndex command do 

}
```

Please guide me thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) `ensureIndex` creates an index on the specified field if the index does not already exist, so subsequent calls do nothing other than checking the index already exists.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer above suggests, multiple calls doesnt do anything.

You are not getting any exception back as MongoDB doesnt throw an exception when you call EnsureIndex the second or third time, it just gives you a JSON that the "Index already exists".

```
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 1,
    "note" : "all indexes already exist",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Just the same way it returns the JSON the First time or when you add an additional Index.

```
{
"createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
"numIndexesBefore" : 1,
"numIndexesAfter" : 2,
"ok" : 1
```

}